# Unable to populate python tkinter Combobox from Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, combobox, tkinter

I am still working on this same program and I made a tiny bit of progress kind of. The application kind of finds the dictionary but all the information is wonky. Here is a picture of what I've got so far.

[Wonky Combobox](http://puu.sh/nyHFm/337d0ed9da.png)

I'm new to python and new to programming. If anyone could help me out with any part of my code I am down to listen and learn! Here's my code so far.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


#Experience Per Level Dictionary
import csv
exptable = csv.DictReader(open('C:/Users/LemDog/Desktop/WinPython 3.5.1.2/python-3.5.1.amd64/Scripts/Ragnarok Stuff/Ragnarok Base Level.csv'))

result = {}
for row in exptable:  # should actually be called `row`
    if row['Current Level'] not in result:
        result[row['Current Level']] = row['Total EXP']


#All the math behind the GetKills Button



#Creates Tkinter Window
root = Tk()
root.title("How many Kills?")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 70 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

expper = StringVar()
currentlevel = StringVar()
desiredlevel = StringVar()
killamount = StringVar()


#OptionMenu From Dictionary
combobox = ttk.Combobox(mainframe)
combobox.grid(column=3, row=1)

combobox.set(result)

for item in [result]:
    combobox.insert(END, result)

#Creats Current Level Text Entry Field
currentlevel = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=10, textvariable=currentlevel)
currentlevel.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

#Creates Exp Per Kill Text Entry Field
expper_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=10, textvariable=expper)
expper_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

#Creats Desired Level Text Entry Field
desiredlevel_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width = 10, textvariable=desiredlevel)
desiredlevel_entry.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))


#Creates Button and Print Label for How Many Kills.
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=killamount).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="How many!?", command=getkills).grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Current Level").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Experience Per Kill").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Desired Level").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Any help at all is appreciated! Thanks for trying in advance!

Comment: since we don't have your data file, it would help if you could simulate the data by using a small hard-coded list of values.

Comment: if you look at [the documentation for the combobox](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Combobox.html) you will see that the `.set()` method just sets the current content, so you are seeing the string representation of your dictionary.  I think you want `values=result` in the combobox constructor

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're setting the entire `__repr__` of your `result` dict as the selected item, and moreover it seems your data is malformed within the list.

Try removing the `.set` and the `combobox.insert` `for` loop and using this:

```
combobox.configure(values=list(result.values())) 
# or result.keys() if that's your intent
```